# Managing cases of an expression containing positive integers

Tags: python, sympy, simplify

I have a bunch of different expression I want to simplify with sympy. One very simple example is

```
form sympy import *
k=Symbol('k',integer=True,nonnegative=True)    
term=( 1-exp(-j*2*pi*k) )/(1-exp(-j*2*pi*k/5) )
```

As a result I get term=0, but I expect that term=5 for k=0, in all other cases term is zero. Is there a simple way to make a simplification for k=0 and k!=0

Comment: For k=0 your expression is `0/0` so undefined.

Comment: yes, but sympy returns zero, so the undefined property disappeared.

Comment: The question says "I expect that term=5 for k=0" but there you have a `0/0`. Maybe it's the limit you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  In a final step I'm interested in getting the limit, but in a first step I would like to know if there is a general way to detect somehow the k values the expression is undefined. As k is nonnegative term=0 for k>0 would be a good result. I was just wondering to get zero for "all" k values I explicitely defined.

Comment: If you don't use assumptions for `k` then you will get an expression that can be separated into numerator and denominator and then you can check separately the conditions for either to be zero.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not clear what you really want but maybe this helps. If you don't declare `k` as an integer the the numerator will not evaluate automatically to zero and then you can manipulate the numerator and denominator expressions separately to find out when they are zero:

```
In [24]: k = Symbol('k')

In [25]: term = (1 - exp(-I*2*pi*k))/(1 - exp(-I*2*pi*k/5))

In [26]: num, den = term.as_numer_denom()

In [27]: solveset(num, k)
Out[27]: ℤ

In [28]: solveset(den, k)
Out[28]: {5⋅n │ n ∊ ℤ}
```